# AWS Cloudfront looking for DNS again and again for same URL/Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-cloudfront

On our website I found that server is looking for DNS again and again for subdomains. Like in the below screenshot static0.domain.com is getting looked up for DNS resolve 3 times(pink bar) and same for the case for static1 and static2. Ideally it should not look for the DNS again if its already found. Because of this website response time is getting delayed.

[image]

Please guide us on this. Testing URL: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/buLq9n/www.tripoto.com

We are using amazon servers with cloudfront.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misinterpreting these results.

Those pink segments indicating the DNS lookup are not redundant requests, as they seem to be parallel in time.  If I need to get multiple objects from a certain host, all those requests have to wait on the first lookup of that host in DNS, and that's what this graph indicates -- multiple requests waiting in parallel for the dna response, not waiting in series or sequentially.  This looks normal.

Your attention should, instead, be drawn to the *yellow* bars, waiting for data from the server... you have connected, and the request has been sent, and you're just waiting for data... in these cases, your server's resonsiveness (your application's responsiveness) seems to be the main factor causing the delay... and these cases seem to be making the largest contribution to the total loading time.

I don't see a Cloudfront or DNS issue here.